# How can i use Aimeos Laravel package Routes as localhost Routes in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-routing, routeconfig

When i run the package from IP that is generated by php artisan serve command, its run easily. It I another icon of the site then it can not find valid route. As example some images is attached. [image]

http://localhost/ecomerce/public/list. 
After clicking the image the valid url does not show and return error like this image  [image]
and URL is "http://localhost/detail/4/Demo_selection_article/1" that is my problem.

If I rewrite the URL as http://localhost/ecomerce/public/detail/4/Demo_selection_article/1 then work well.
The package I use that link is https://github.com/aimeos/aimeos-laravel.

How can I solve this problem? Pleas help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel router expects that ./public/ is your document root, so your problem isn't related to Aimeos if I'm correct but is a common Laravel problem.